# How to deploy a plugin for IntelliJ with addition resources?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deployment, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

I'm trying to deploy a plugin project for `IntelliJ`.

In addition to the source code, I have images, third party libraries and more.

I want to deploy the all parts to a jar file, but when I click on `Prepare plugin module XXX for deployment` it's just deploy the source code only.

How I can to deploy the all project plugin files to a jar file in `IntelliJ`?

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation here that mentions including icons in the plugin.

It seems if you mark the directory as a `source root`, this might be enough for the resource to be packaged in the plugin?

http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/work_with_icons_and_images.html

As for third party libraries, if you tried already setting them up as a project library and that didn't work, then I'm not sure.